# What can we do to help boost traffic now that the latest school session has started?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Now that school is in session, there will be zillions of parents with school-age children, and they'll all have lots of questions.

Since there are already a lot of parents here with older children, Parenting SE has a shot at having the best answers to those questions — better than any of those, you know, competitive sites. Essentially, this is a great time to recruit new members!

#### What can you do to help?

Comment: A+ all around. I'd like to add this: Parenting.SE is about to have an advertisement go live on the PTA website. For those of you unaware, the [Parent Teacher Association](http://pta.org) is a major national organization in the United States that connects parents and teacher of (usually) primary-school-aged children. The PTA site has a page full of parenting resources ("Topics") and it is on this page that our static ad will be placed for all of September -- their busiest month! Having more primary-school questions on the front page will benefit ***all*** of us, and this community at large!

Comment: @Aarthi: Awesome idea. All the better reason to have have some great questions and answers for them when new users arrive!

Comment: For the sake of completeness: [This is the PTA page with Parent Resource Links](http://pta.org/4305.htm).

Comment: Also seems like a great chance to get an ad on the rest of the SE network to bring in folks that already get SE and happen to also have kids heading off to school.

Answer (score 1):

1. As your children start the school year, whenever you have questions, no matter how silly, ***ask them here***. You're not the only one having that question. Millions of other people will, too. Ask them even if you think you're going to be able to find the answer yourself… and if you *do* find the answer, go ahead and answer it yourself.
2. When answering these questions, do everything you can to overkill it. Don't just answer with a hyperlink to some other discussion group somewhere. Write a detailed, ultra-clear answer that is just as complete and clear as you can muster. Help us have the best possible answers to these common problems and questions parents have with their older children, too!
3. If a question comes in that is unclear, badly written, badly formatted, or in bad English, edit it into shape. We've always encouraged edits that improve spelling, grammar, and clarity. Make every question count!

This is a great opportunity to build up a body of answers to common school-age question that will be super-popular in the coming weeks as everyone returns to school.

Those questions will bring in lots of traffic from search engines and if Parenting SE continues to have great answers like we have in the past, we stand a chance of attracting some great new users who will add value for years to come!

<sub>*Shamelessly adapted from [Joel's successful promotion](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/589/3) to build new content for Apple SE. It works!*</sub>